# Javascript pathname referrer

Tags: javascript, location, referrer, pathname

How can do the same function in javascript that is document.location.pathname - except with the referrer? so something like document.referrer.pathname?

Thanks.

Comment: What about just trying document.referrer.  For instance:
    alert(document.referrer);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only extract needed part manually:

```js
document.referrer.replace(/^[^:]+:\/\/[^/]+/, '').replace(/#.*/, '')
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct as the `document.location.pathname` will strip the parameters of the URL as well.

You need to use:
`document.referrer.replace(/^[^:]+:\/\/[^/]+/, '').replace(/#.*/, '').replace(/\?.*/, '')`

to also remove the parameters of the referrer.

Answer (score 7):

You can extract the pathname from the `document.referrer` and parse it with [`new URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) with the following code

```
const url = new URL(document.referrer)
url.pathname
```

Be sure to polyfill URL for IE 10 and below, easily done with https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=URL

Comment: `/* Disable minification (remove '.min' from URL path) for more info */` is the error when clicking your link and `/* No polyfills found for current settings */` is the error when removing `min`. Perhaps you meant to post something else?

Comment: Thanks @AbandonedCart for letting me know, I have changed the Polyfill.io link

Comment: Note that the URL constructor will throw when not given a valid URL (like the empty string when no referrer is set). Depending on the use-case, providing a base URL might be a good way to prevent this: `new URL(document.referrer, "http://example.com/")`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.referrer` to obtain the URL of the referring document. Is that what you mean??

Comment: No I want just the path so if http://www.google.com/sdfhisdfsdf, I just want the /sdfhisdfsdf part..lol

Comment: Aaah... I think you have to parse yourself.. maybe regex to rescue??